# finding xml parts in a sentence with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have such a line:

```
<bpt i="1" type="1" x="1" />und ZF-Getriebe <ept i="1" />TipMatic <ph x="2" type="2" />Lite (&lt;/cf&gt;6AS850, 6AS800, 6AS1000)
```

And I want a regex which will extract the xml parts, so at the end the sentence will be:

```
__xml__und ZF-Getriebe __xml__TipMatic __xml__Lite (&lt;/cf&gt;6AS850, 6AS800, 6AS1000)
```

What might be a possible regex for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the xml tags are always open-closed, this might do what you want. It would remain for you to put the xml's in.

```
>>> line = '''<bpt i="1" type="1" x="1" />und ZF-Getriebe <ept i="1" />TipMatic <ph x="2" type="2" />Lite (&lt;/cf&gt;6AS850, 6AS800, 6AS1000)'''
>>> import re
>>> pieces = []
>>> pos = 0
>>> for m in re.finditer(r'(<[^\/]+\/>)', line):
...     line[m.span()[0]:m.span()[1]]
...     pieces.append(line[pos:m.span()[0]])
...     pos = m.span()[1]
...     
'<bpt i="1" type="1" x="1" />'
'<ept i="1" />'
'<ph x="2" type="2" />'
>>> pieces.append(line[m.span()[1]:])
>>> pieces
['', 'und ZF-Getriebe ', 'TipMatic ', 'Lite (&lt;/cf&gt;6AS850, 6AS800, 6AS1000)']
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any good way to do this - afaik, regex is not very good at extracting XML. Probably your best bet is to use BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs2 import BeautifulSoup as BS
xml ="""
 <bpt i="1" type="1" x="1" />und ZF-Getriebe <ept i="1" />TipMatic <ph x="2" type="2" />Lite (&lt;/cf&gt;6AS850, 6AS800, 6AS1000)
 """
 a = BS(xml)
 list(a.strings)
 [u'und ZF-Getriebe ', u'TipMatic ', u'Lite (</cf>6AS850, 6AS800, 6AS1000)\n']
```

You can sort of walk through the list as well, by doing

```
 # It adds <html><body> in front of it, so this gets around that
 cl = list(a.children.next().children.next().children)
 cl
 [<bpt i="1" type="1" x="1"></bpt>,
 u'und ZF-Getriebe ',
 <ept i="1"></ept>,
 u'TipMatic ',
 <ph type="2" x="2"></ph>,
 u'Lite (</cf>6AS850, 6AS800, 6AS1000)\n']
```

You can check the type of each child to see if it's a string or XML.

Comment: Thank you Corley, but this answer does not solve my problem.